# How do set all Sitecore Cookies as HttpOnly

Tags: configuration, patch-configuration

I'm new to Sitecore, for my new Project, I need to make a few customizations in cookie creation.
Is there any way to force the Sitecore to create cookies with HttpOnly as 'true'? I'm using Sitecore 10 version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Raman's comment, here is an addition to this, if you want to set cookie HttpOnly using code, you can do as follow

```
private const string helloCookieName = "HELLO_COOKIE";
var httpResponse = HttpContext.Current?.Response;
if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(helloCookieName))
{
var helloCookie = httpResponse.Cookies.Get(helloCookieName);
helloCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
helloCookie.Secure = true;
}
```

for global-level change, you can do as Raman suggests.
Configure the default values of cookies in the `<system.web>` section of the `web.config` file as follows:

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen , is there way to create a Sitecore Pipeline processor that can run after cookie creation ?
`<processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"                          type="MySite.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.CookieProcessor, MySite.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" />`  this is working for #lang.  But I need to target few more cookie types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674628/changing-sitecore-cookie-config-as-httponly - @Labit - check this, I think this question is your answer to updating existing cookie, I did not try it, but you should.